# $k\mu(X)\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mu(A_i)$ for $\mu(X) \le \infty$.

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space, $\mu(X) \le \infty$ (one can assume that $\mu$ is a Lebesgue measure). Subsets $A_i \subset X$ ($i=1, ..., n$) are measurable. For every point $x \in X$ there are at least $k$ subsets $A_i$ which contain this point. Prove that $k\mu(X)\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mu(A_i)$.

It's clear that $\cup_{i=1}^{n} A_i \supset X$. It seems that there are at least $k$ different subcollections of $A_i$ which cover whole $X$. But I can't prove this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=1_{A_1}(x)+\dots+1_{A_n}(x)$. Then since each $x\in X$ is contained in at least $k$ of the $A_i$, it follows that $f(x)\geq k$ for all $x$, hence
$$ k\mu(X)=\int_Xk\;d\mu\leq \int_Xf\;d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^n\int_X1_{A_i}\;d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^n\mu(A_i)$$

Answer (score 1):

Think about integrals. Let $\chi_{A_i}$ be the characteristic function of
$A_i$. Then $\int\chi_{A_i}\,d\mu=\mu(A_i)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n\chi_{A_i}\ge k\chi_X$. Now integrate.